Using the card hover effect with the bootstrap modal causes issues
I am currently designing a webpage using bootstrap and EJS. I want to create a modal window when one button is clicked to show additional information, and when an X button or "close" button is pressed, the modal window is closed.
However, the transform effect inside the card:hover css effect is messing up the modal window.
For starters, here's the rough code
<%- include('_header'); -%> << header includes Bootstrap css, js and Font Awesome css.
<style>
  /* Card Style */
  .card {
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  .card:hover {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  }
  .card-header {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  }
  .badge-custom {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  /* Modal Style */
  .modal-header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .modal-body {
    padding: 2rem;
  }
  .modal-footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  
</style>

...

<div class="container mt-5">

...

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
      <div class="card bg-light">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h5 class="card-title mb-0">고객</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <% project.consumers.forEach(consumer => { %>
              <li class="list-group-item bg-light">
                <i class="fas fa-user-tie me-2"></i>
                <%= consumer.name %>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#consumerModal<%= consumer.id %>">
                  <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                </button>

                <!-- Modal Start -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="consumerModal<%= consumer.id %>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="consumerModalLabel<%= consumer.id %>" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="consumerModalLabel<%= consumer.id %>"><%= consumer.name %>의 상세 정보</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <% Object.entries(consumer.custom_attributes).forEach(([attrKey, attrValue]) => { %>
                          <p><strong><%= attrKey %>:</strong> <%= attrValue.content %></p>
                        <% }); %>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">닫기</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal End -->

              </li>
            <% }); %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

...

</div>

So when I press the button below, a modal window should appear in the center of the screen.
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#consumerModal<%= consumer.id %>">
                  <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                </button>

However, the first results were as follows.
https://i.imgur.com/PysG6V1.gif
As you can see in the image, a modal window appears in two places, and it flickers so fast that I can't press the button. I asked ChatGPT to solve this problem and he recommended using the following JS to temporarily disable the transform.
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
    var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

    modals.forEach(function(modal) {
      modal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function () {
        cards.forEach(function(card) {
          card.style.transform = 'none';
        });
      });
      
      modal.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        cards.forEach(function(card) {
          card.style.transform = '';
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>

This eliminated the flickering modal window, but introduced another problem. The modal window would appear briefly in the div area that fetches the modal window, then disappear. Of course, many visitors will pass by without seeing this brief modal window, but I don't think this is a good idea.
https://i.imgur.com/ysUP72n.gif
transform: translateY(-5px);
In my code, if just one line above inside the CSS is missing, everything works fine.
https://i.imgur.com/7K05E6Y.gif
I would gladly give up the effect of the card moving slightly when the user hovers over the card component to avoid this complication. However, the current situation doesn't make logical sense to me, and I need to know why it's happening so I can move on to the next step. Why is this happening?
Attempted to inject Javascript, attempted to modify CSS.

Your forEach loop is rendering the button (to open Modal) and number of modals on the bases of number of customers. I suggest don't do that... instead Keep that modal outside foreach loop and hide/show it with javaScript Function. you can pass values in function and use those values in modal. it's possible .

@PranSukh Oh my goodness, you solved my problem in a single step, even removing the script that GPT told me to add, now the modal window works fine. I guess it was a mistake to create the modal window multiple times. After all, simply asking GPT to design the frontend still seems problematic. This problem has been solved neatly. Thanks a lot.

I'm glad that helps.... would you please explore the answer and give a upvote if that works for you or you understood the concept ... Thanks in advance .....



function functionToOpenModal(param1, param2){

 var x = document.getElementById("ModalTOShow");
 var body = document.getElementById("ModalBody");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    body.innerHTML = param1 ;
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }

}
<style>
  /* Card Style */
  .card {
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  .card:hover {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  }
  .card-header {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  }
  .badge-custom {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  /* Modal Style */
  .modal-header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .modal-body {
    padding: 2rem;
  }
  .modal-footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  
</style>
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalTOShow" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true" style ="display:none">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="consumerModalLabelId">Modal Title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Close Button</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body" id="ModalBody">
                       
                          <p id="para"><strong id="strong"></strong> </p>
                        
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Other functinal Button of modal</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
        //forEach start()
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" onClick="functionToOpenModal('customer Name:jinga','c attribute: lolopipo')">Button to open modal</button>
        // this will render number of fuction calls with different params and those params will be visible/set in modal.
        //forEach end()



Your forEach loop is rendering the button (to open Modal) and number of modals on the bases of number of customers. I suggest don't do that... instead Keep that modal outside foreach loop and hide/show it with javaScript Function. you can pass values in function and use those values in modal. it's possible .

function functionToOpenModal(param1, param2, ....otherParams){

 var x = document.getElementById("ModalTOShow");
 var body = document.getElementById("ModalBody");
 [you can get all the elements where you want to put the value with the elementId]
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    body.value = param1 or param2 or otherParams....
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    body.style.display = "none";
  }

}


            <div class="modal fade" id="ModalTOShow" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="consumerModalLabel<%= consumer.id %>" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="consumerModalLabel<%= consumer.id %>"><%= consumer.name %>의 상세 정보</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body" id="ModalBody">
                    <% Object.entries(consumer.custom_attributes).forEach(([attrKey, attrValue]) => { %>
                      <p><strong><%= attrKey %>:</strong> <%= attrValue.content %></p>
                    <% }); %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">닫기</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal End -->

<% project.consumers.forEach(consumer => { %>
              <li class="list-group-item bg-light">
                <i class="fas fa-user-tie me-2"></i>
                <%= consumer.name %>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#consumerModal<%= consumer.id %> onClick=functionToOpenModal(<%customer.id%>,<%customer.otherInfo%>,...so on)">
                  <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                </button>
                </li>
                <%}%>

                ```
                
                


Thank you. My problem is solved perfectly, have a nice day!
